# Design Youtube Direct Lite

Tags: google-api

I want users to be able to share conversation videos to Youtube. The first approach is let them upload to my own channel

1) Advantage: Full control over uploaded videos.
2) Disadvantage: Quota limit, system not scalable

Use a system similar to Youtube directlite, let the users upload to their own channel

1) Advantage: Scalability, quota 
2) Disadvantage: they can delete/make the recording private. My application won't be able to retrieve those videos.

How to overcome this problem?